# Testing vue components that has vuex

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I'm having trouble testing my vue component using the vuex inside it.
This is one of my mapGetters

methods

```
listaSatelite() {
  if (this.getCropsSelected._id!=undefined) {
}}
```

And this is the error i'm getting:

```
Cannot read property '_modulesNamespaceMap' of undefined
```

computed

```
 ...mapGetters("property",["getCropsSelected"]),
```

my spec fyle

```
import {shallowMount,createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import sateliteComponent from '@/components/satelite/listaSatelite.vue'
import sateliteStore from '@/core/modules/satelite/index.js'

var vueWithVuex = createLocalVue()
vueWithVuex.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    sateliteStore
})
describe('testes componente satelite', () => {

    test('instanciado', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(sateliteComponent)
        console.log(wrapper)

    });
});
```

erro log

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_modulesNamespaceMap' of undefined

      119 |         },
      120 |         listaSatelite() {
    > 121 |           if (this.getCropsSelected._id!=undefined) {
          | ^
      122 |             this.listSatelite({
      123 |               startDate: this.getCropsSelected.startDate,
      124 |               endDate: this.getCropsSelected.endDate
```

In my console it is pointing and showing that the error is in the method, as if he had not been able to import or find this getter

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be most welcome!
If someone has a tutorial on how to test the vue with the vuex inside, but test the component, the ones I found on the internet are tests of the vuex itself

Comment: Can you provide a test example? You most likely need to [mock Vuex](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html) starting with `const localVue = createLocalVue(); localVue.use(Vuex);` before your tests

Comment: I provided my test file

Comment: About the error with `_modulesNamespaceMap`, do you use namespaced modules? When running the app, is your `listaSatelite.vue` component instantiated properly?

Comment: I use namespaced when it is not necessary to globally install that store, that component is "called" in another component.

Comment: Provided more info about the error